# Creating a list of expression trees in Prolog

Tags: prolog, expression-trees

Let's consider the following prolog code that allows me to form expression trees:

```
plus(_,_).

eval(A, A) :- number(A).
eval(plus(A, B), R) :- eval(A, A_R), eval(B, B_R), R is A_R+B_R.
```

I can easily define and evaluate expression trees the following way:

```
eval(plus(1,2), R).
```

which evaluates to

```
R=3
```

Some languages allows us to build expression trees and then assign them to a variable, so they can be later used. In pseudo-code:

```
my_expr = plus(plus(1, 2), 3)
```

I'm wondering whether with my current tree representation I'm capable of achieving a similar result? I'd want to have a list with a different expression tree in each node. Something along the lines of

```
[ plus(1, 2), plus(3,plus(2,1)), 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example

```
my_expr = plus(plus(1, 2), 3)
```

You cannot do that b/c the left hand and right hand side of the = do not match.  If my_expr was a variable (uppercase), this would be true and would cause my_expr to be bound to the tree plus(plus(1, 2), 3).  Check this out -

```
?- My_expr = plus(plus(1, 2), 3), 
   eval(plus(My_expr, My_expr), Times2).

Times2 = 12
```

My_expr is a perfectly legitimate structure for you to put into a list or call a downstream expression with.